# How to fix error in fslvbm_2_template where no template_4D_GM file is created

Tags: bash

I am running a VBM analysis in FSL. I have searched on the JISC Mail archives for solutions to this error but have had no luck. I have a lot of available space on my laptop, so it is not a space issue. I have also had this problem across multiple Mac systems. Any help will be greatly appreciated, I have been struggling with this for days.

When I run the code "fslvbm_2_template -n" I am expecting to create a file named template_4D_GM but get this error code in the output:

```
Running segmentation: ID=64663
Running initial registration: ID=64926

Image Exception : #63 :: No image files match: 1_002_s_####_struc_GM_to_T
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: No image files match: 1_002_s_####_struc_GM_to_T
./fslvbm2c: line 13: 68739 Abort trap: 6 
$FSLDIR/bin/fslmerge -t template_4D_GM $mergelist

Image Exception : #63 :: No image files match: template_4D_GM
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: No image files match: template_4D_GM
./fslvbm2c: line 14: 68740 Abort trap: 6
$FSLDIR/bin/fslmaths template_4D_GM -Tmean template_GM

Image Exception : #63 :: No image files match: template_GM
No image files match: template_GM
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslswapdim: line 107: [: =: unary operator expected
Image Exception : #63 :: No image files match: template_GM
No image files match: template_GM
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslswapdim: line 115: [: -gt: unary operator expected

Image Exception : #63 :: No image files match: template_GM
No image files match: template_GM
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslswapdim: line 117: [: -gt: unary operator expected

Image Exception : #63 :: No image files match: template_GM
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: No image files match: template_GM
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslswapdim: line 184: 68769 Abort trap: 6           $comm

Image Exception : #63 :: No image files match: template_GM
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: No image files match: template_GM
./fslvbm2c: line 16: 68770 Abort trap: 6
$FSLDIR/bin/fslmaths template_GM -add template_GM_flipped -div 2 template_GM_init

Creating first-pass template: ID=
Running registration to first-pass template: ID=The command you have requested cannot be found or is not executable
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fsl_sub: line 514: you: command not found
Creating second-pass template: ID=
Study-specific template will be created, when complete, check results with:
fslview struc/template_4D_GM
and turn on the movie loop to check all subjects, then run:
fslview  /usr/local/fsl/data/standard/tissuepriors/avg152T1_gray  struc/template_GM
to check general alignment of mean GM template vs. original standard space template.
```

When running "fslvbm_2_template -n" I find that fslvbm2a and fslvbm2b will run without error but I hit the problem at fslvbm2c. When I run this specific piece of code from the fslvbm_2_template - FSLVBM template creation (http://ftp.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/pub/dist/freesurfer/tutorial_packages/OSX/fsl_501/bin/fslvbm_2_template):

```
MacBook-Pro:struc name$ cat <<stage_tpl3 > fslvbm2c
#!/bin/sh

> if [ -f ../template_list ] ; then

>   template_list=\`cat ../template_list\`

>   template_list=\`\$FSLDIR/bin/remove_ext \$template_list\`

> else

>   template_list=\`echo *_struc.* | sed 's/_struc\./\./g'\`

>   template_list=\`\$FSLDIR/bin/remove_ext \$template_list | sort -u\`

>     echo "WARNING - study-specific template will be created from ALL input data - may not be group-size matched!!!"

> fi

> for g in \$template_list ; do

>     mergelist="\$mergelist \${g}_struc_GM_to_T"

> done

> \$FSLDIR/bin/fslmerge -t template_4D_GM \$mergelist

> \$FSLDIR/bin/fslmaths template_4D_GM -Tmean template_GM

> \$FSLDIR/bin/fslswapdim template_GM -x y z template_GM_flipped

> \$FSLDIR/bin/fslmaths template_GM -add template_GM_flipped -div 2 template_GM_init

> stage_tpl3

MacBook-Pro:struc name$ chmod +x fslvbm2c

MacBook-Pro:struc name$ fslvbm2c_id=`fsl_sub -j $fslvbm2b_id -T 15 -N 
fslvbm2c ./fslvbm2c`

MacBook-Pro:struc name$ echo Creating first-pass template: `ID=$fslvbm2c_id`
Creating first-pass template: ID=The command you have requested cannot be found or is not executable
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and when debugging I found out that the problem was in the line 94 `T=${FSLDIR}/data/standard/tissuepriors/avg152T1_gray` (in `fslvbm_2_template`). The problem is that this image (used as template) is a .hdr but it needs to be a `nii.gz` to be readable by the program. So, the solution is to download an `avg152T1_gray.nii.gz` and replaced the .hdr image for the new one. I changed the `avg152T1_gray.nii.gz` name to `avg152T1_grayNI.nii.gz` and copied it into the same folder (tissuepriors).

`#T=${FSLDIR}/data/standard/tissuepriors/avg152T1_gray` (commented .hdr image that don't work)

`T=${FSLDIR}/data/standard/tissuepriors/avg152T1_grayNI` (.nii.gz image that works fine for me)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making `fslreorient2std` - to all NIFTI images before doing the `template_list` (STEP 1 in FSLVBM Analysis). I think this tool make the correct orientations so that `fslvbm_2_template` can read in a fast and easy way each image in order to average them with the `avg152T1_gray` template.